# Clearing out file on bootstrap fileupload

Tags: jquery

Hi i have this code on file upload

```
 <div class="span7">
     <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="input-append" style="width: 100%;">
           <div class="uneditable-input span4" style="width: 80%; height: 40px; line-height: 30px;">
             <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists" id="iconupload"></i>
             <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
           </div>
           <span class="btn btn-file inputbutton btn-info btn-fileupload-medium">
           <span class="fileupload-new">Browse</span>
           <span class="fileupload-exists">Browse</span>
             <input type="file" id="fileXLS" name="fileXLS" />
           </span>
           <a href="#" id="removefile" class="btn fileupload-exists inputbutton btn-info" data-dismiss="fileupload">remove</a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Is there a way to clear the file after processing the upload using jQuery without using the remove button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the `.fileupload('clear')` method ?

http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.1/javascript.html#fileupload

scroll down to the "Methods" section

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reset the value in the success callback of your upload script:

```
$('#fileXLS').val('');
```